# confluence wiki API detele attachment

Tags: confluence

I want to delete one page's attachments with Python by Confluence API but it doesn't provide such API. Is there any method？
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X86rn.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Confluence API does provide a possibility to get the page attachment list (or a single one by its file name) and delete all one by one. To do so try something like this (converting JavaScript to Python first):

```js
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic <base64 encoded username:password>',
  'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'
};

// this might differ depending on the server configuration:
var apiRoot = 'https://confluence.host.net/rest/api';

// page id:
var containerId = '171607042'

// get all attachments:
var getAttachmentsUrl = `${apiRoot}/content/${containerId}/child/attachment`;

// get only the one attachment:
var fileName = 'some.file';
getAttachmentsUrl += `?fileName=${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;

fetch(getAttachmentsUrl, {headers})
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(o => Promise.all(o.results.map(
    i=>fetch(i._links.self, {method: "DELETE", headers})
  )))
  .then(r => console.log('r', r));
```

Comment: "nocheck" was changed to "no-check" a few years back